# Sefer Besamim Rosh

Tags: history, jewish-books

Who wrote the Sefer Besamim Rosh?

Comment: [tag:mistakes]?

Answer (score 11):

[Here](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2005/10/besamim-rosh.html)'s a nice writeup. It was published by [R' Saul Berlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Berlin), with the claim that only the commentary part was by him, but the core responsa were by [the Rosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asher_ben_Jehiel). Many (maybe most) scholars now believe that R' Saul Berlin wrote both parts and misattributed the responsa to the Rosh.

[R' Rakeffet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Rakeffet-Rothkoff) is doing a fascinating lecture series on this work, including a great deal of discussion of why it's now taken to be a literary forgery. You can hear what he's said so far by going [here](http://www.yutorah.org/search/?teacher=80135) and listening to the lectures marked "Responsa," starting "2010-10-24 Responsa 06." You can also subscribe to an ongoing feed of his lectures (both Responsa and Jewish History, which is equally fascinating) using this [RSS link](http://www.yutorah.org/rss.cfm/teacher/80135/Rabbi_Aaron_Rakeffet-Rothkoff/301).

Comment: "misattributed": Oops!

Comment: +1 for answering a question I was about to ask with your additional info and sources here.